# Issues with using Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am working through a basic example if using Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka Streams:

```
package pl.piomin.samples.kafka.stock;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde;
import pl.piomin.samples.kafka.stock.logic.OrderLogic;
import pl.piomin.samples.kafka.stock.model.Order;
import pl.piomin.samples.kafka.stock.model.Transaction;
import pl.piomin.samples.kafka.stock.model.TransactionTotal;
import pl.piomin.samples.kafka.stock.model.TransactionTotalWithProduct;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class StockService {

    private static long transactionId = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StockService.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    OrderLogic logic;

    @Bean
    public BiConsumer<KStream<Long, Order>, KStream<Long, Order>> orders() {
        return (orderBuy, orderSell) -> orderBuy
                .merge(orderSell)
                .peek((k, v) -> {
                    log.info("New({}): {}", k, v);
                    logic.add(v);
                });
    }

    @Bean
    public BiFunction<KStream<Long, Order>, KStream<Long, Order>, KStream<Long, Transaction>> transactions() {
        return (orderBuy, orderSell) -> orderBuy
                .selectKey((k, v) -> v.getProductId())
                .join(orderSell.selectKey((k, v) -> v.getProductId()),
                        this::execute,
                        JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(10)),
                        StreamJoined.with(Serdes.Integer(), new JsonSerde<>(Order.class), new JsonSerde<>(Order.class)))
                .filterNot((k, v) -> v == null)
                .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v.getId(), v))
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Done -> {}", v));
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<KStream<Long, Transaction>> total() {
        KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(
                "all-transactions-store");
        return transactions -> transactions
                .groupBy((k, v) -> v.getStatus(),
                        Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(Transaction.class)))
                .aggregate(
                        TransactionTotal::new,
                        (k, v, a) -> {
                            a.setCount(a.getCount() + 1);
                            a.setProductCount(a.getProductCount() + v.getAmount());
                            a.setAmount(a.getAmount() + (v.getPrice() * v.getAmount()));
                            return a;
                        },
                        Materialized.<String, TransactionTotal> as(storeSupplier)
                            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                            .withValueSerde(new JsonSerde<>(TransactionTotal.class)))
                .toStream()
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Total: {}", v));
    }

    @Bean
    public BiConsumer<KStream<Long, Transaction>, KStream<Long, Order>> totalPerProduct() {
        KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(
                "transactions-per-product-store");
        return (transactions, orders) -> transactions
                .selectKey((k, v) -> v.getSellOrderId())
                .join(orders.selectKey((k, v) -> v.getId()),
                        (t, o) -> new TransactionTotalWithProduct(t, o.getProductId()),
                        JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(10)),
                        StreamJoined.with(Serdes.Long(),
                                new JsonSerde<>(Transaction.class),
                                new JsonSerde<>(Order.class)))
                .groupBy((k, v) -> v.getProductId(),
                        Grouped.with(Serdes.Integer(), new JsonSerde<>(TransactionTotalWithProduct.class)))
                .aggregate(
                        TransactionTotal::new,
                        (k, v, a) -> {
                            a.setCount(a.getCount() + 1);
                            a.setProductCount(a.getProductCount() + v.getTransaction().getAmount());
                            a.setAmount(a.getAmount() + (v.getTransaction().getPrice() * v.getTransaction().getAmount()));
                            return a;
                        },
                        Materialized.<Integer, TransactionTotal> as(storeSupplier)
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.Integer())
                                .withValueSerde(new JsonSerde<>(TransactionTotal.class)))
                .toStream()
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Total per product({}): {}", k, v));
    }

    @Bean
    public BiConsumer<KStream<Long, Transaction>, KStream<Long, Order>> latestPerProduct() {
        WindowBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.persistentWindowStore(
                "latest-transactions-per-product-store", Duration.ofSeconds(30), Duration.ofSeconds(30), false);
        return (transactions, orders) -> transactions
                .selectKey((k, v) -> v.getSellOrderId())
                .join(orders.selectKey((k, v) -> v.getId()),
                        (t, o) -> new TransactionTotalWithProduct(t, o.getProductId()),
                        JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(10)),
                        StreamJoined.with(Serdes.Long(), new JsonSerde<>(Transaction.class), new JsonSerde<>(Order.class)))
                .groupBy((k, v) -> v.getProductId(), Grouped.with(Serdes.Integer(), new JsonSerde<>(TransactionTotalWithProduct.class)))
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
                .aggregate(
                        TransactionTotal::new,
                        (k, v, a) -> {
                            a.setCount(a.getCount() + 1);
                            a.setAmount(a.getAmount() + v.getTransaction().getAmount());
                            return a;
                        },
                        Materialized.<Integer, TransactionTotal> as(storeSupplier)
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.Integer())
                                .withValueSerde(new JsonSerde<>(TransactionTotal.class)))
                .toStream()
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Total per product last 30s({}): {}", k, v));
    }

    private Transaction execute(Order orderBuy, Order orderSell) {
        if (orderBuy.getAmount() >= orderSell.getAmount()) {
            int count = Math.min(orderBuy.getProductCount(), orderSell.getProductCount());
//            log.info("Executed: orderBuy={}, orderSell={}", orderBuy.getId(), orderSell.getId());
            boolean allowed = logic.performUpdate(orderBuy.getId(), orderSell.getId(), count);
            if (!allowed)
                return null;
            else
                return new Transaction(
                    ++transactionId,
                    orderBuy.getId(),
                    orderSell.getId(),
                    Math.min(orderBuy.getProductCount(), orderSell.getProductCount()),
                    (orderBuy.getAmount() + orderSell.getAmount()) / 2,
                    LocalDateTime.now(),
                    "NEW");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my application.yml file:

```
spring.application.name: stock-service

spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers: '10.0.0.24:29092'

spring.cloud.stream.function.definition: orders;transactions;total;totalPerProduct;latestPerProduct

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.orders-in-0.destination: orders.buy
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.orders-in-1.destination: orders.sell
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.orders.applicationId: orders

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.transactions-in-0.destination: orders.buy
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.transactions-in-1.destination: orders.sell
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.transactions-out-0.destination: transactions
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.transactions.applicationId: transactions

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.total-in-0.destination: transactions
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.total.applicationId: total

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.totalPerProduct-in-0.destination: transactions
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.totalPerProduct-in-1.destination: orders.sell
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.totalPerProduct.applicationId: totalPerProduct

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.latestPerProduct-in-0.destination: transactions
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.latestPerProduct-in-1.destination: orders.sell
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.latestPerProduct.applicationId: latestPerProduct

spring.output.ansi.enabled: ALWAYS

logging.pattern.console: "%clr(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}){blue} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){yellow} %clr(:){red} %clr(%m){faint}%n"

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"
```

When I attempt to run this StockService.java I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "total-800123ae-f58c-49c6-b8fa-c4fedef8d433-StreamThread-1" Exception in thread "totalPerProduct-6f0d157a-85dd-41a4-82c2-26137fe9bf42-StreamThread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.rocksdb.DBOptions
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBStore.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.KeyValueToTimestampedKeyValueByteStoreAdapter.init(KeyValueToTimestampedKeyValueByteStoreAdapter.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.init(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.init(CachingKeyValueStore.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$init$1(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.init(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.registerStateStores(ProcessorStateManager.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateManagerUtil.registerStateStores(StateManagerUtil.java:103)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeIfNeeded(StreamTask.java:210)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.tryToCompleteRestoration(TaskManager.java:473)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.initializeAndRestorePhase(StreamThread.java:754)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:636)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:564)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:523)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/d_/ytnkcdl91sz3f9tvvjppg7140000gp/T/librocksdbjni10553510461735012548.jnilib
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2393)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35)
    at org.rocksdb.DBOptions.<clinit>(DBOptions.java:21)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBStore.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.KeyValueToTimestampedKeyValueByteStoreAdapter.init(KeyValueToTimestampedKeyValueByteStoreAdapter.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.init(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:54)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.init(CachingKeyValueStore.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$init$1(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.init(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.registerStateStores(ProcessorStateManager.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateManagerUtil.registerStateStores(StateManagerUtil.java:103)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeIfNeeded(StreamTask.java:210)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.tryToCompleteRestoration(TaskManager.java:473)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.initializeAndRestorePhase(StreamThread.java:754)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:636)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:564)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:523)
```

What should I do ro correct this?

Comment: Looks like some classpath issues. What version of the binder are you using? and the Spring Boot version? Any chance you can share your full maven/gradle configuration?

Comment: I put the config here:  https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/6c295ca5cfc18ce502dcdac8af368854

Comment: I noticed that you are using Java 17. The proper java 17 support for boot/spring-cloud (Spring Cloud Stream included) is only available for Boot 3.0/Spring Cloud Stream 4.0 etc. I am not saying that this is the issue you are running into, but since you are having CP issues, that is something that you may want to double-check.